# Make an Http request through a Lambda Func

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I'm trying make httpclient requests through a helper function that will manage a circuitbreaker polly policy.

I'm trying to call it like so

```
var response = clientFactory.MakeRequest(() => client.GetAsync("/"));
```

Inside of the client factory I have my circuit breaker policy defined and I'm trying to execute the lambda above using that policy like so

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(Func<HttpResponseMessage> request)
{
     var response = policy.ExecuteAsync(() => request.Invoke());
     return response;
}
```

I'm fairly new to Lambda's as a whole and passing it as a function gets more confusing. How do I configure the function and the first line of code to execute the client and return the `HttpResponseMessage`? I don't think `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` or `Func<HttpResponseMessage>` is correct

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, that you read some information on async/await (not lambdas) as this is the key to understanding how to achieve it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

You are using asynchronous programming so must decide, whether you want to have asynchronous method MakeRequest or you want synchronous one. If you want synchronous (but then - no need for using ExecuteAsync. I suppose, that there is Execute() alternative) simple write :

```
public HttpResponseMessage MakeRequest(Func<HttpResponseMessage> request)
  {
     var response = policy.ExecuteAsync(() => request.Invoke());
     return await response;
  }
```

if you want asynchronous :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(Func<HttpResponseMessage> request)
{
    var response = policy.ExecuteAsync(() => request.Invoke());
    return response;
}

public void MyMethodUsingAsync()
{
    var responsePromises = MakeRequest(() => {...});
    ///do some job wich will be done before response is retrieved (not waiting for it); and if you need it - use await
    var responseReceived = await responsePromises;
}
```

Comment: I've downvoted your post because your first code sample does not compile since you try to use the `await` keyword without `async`. Your second code snippet does not compile either since you try to use the `await` keyword inside a sync method (`void`).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from this line:

```
var response = clientFactory.MakeRequest(() => client.GetAsync("/"));
```

If `client` is an `HttpClient` instance then the `GetAsync` returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. So, what you have passed as a parameter to the `MakeRequest` is a function which returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. Without defining a custom delegate you can use the `Func` type to describe this intent: `Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>`.

---

So, your `MakeRequest` should anticipate this kind of parameter to be able to decorate it with a policy (or chain of policies). The actual implementation of the `MakeRequest` can be written in so many different ways:

#### Option 1

- Passing `request` to `ExecuteAsync` as it is
- Returning the result of `ExecuteAsync` as it is

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> request)
   => policy.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

#### Option 2

- Passing `request` to `ExecuteAsync` as it is
- Awaiting the result of `ExecuteAsync`

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> request)
   => await policy.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

#### Option 3

- Passing a function to `ExecuteAsync` which calls the `request`
- Returning the result of `ExecuteAsync` as it is

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> request)
   => policy.ExecuteAsync(() => request());
```

#### Option 4

- Passing a function to `ExecuteAsync` which calls the `request`
- Awaiting the result of `ExecuteAsync`

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> request)
   => await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => request());
```

#### Option 5

- Passing an async function to `ExecuteAsync` which awaits the `request`
- Returning the result of `ExecuteAsync` as it is

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> request)
   => policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await request());
```

#### Option 6

- Passing an async function to `ExecuteAsync` which awaits the `request`
- Awaiting the result of `ExecuteAsync`

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> request)
   => await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await request());
```

Even though Option 1 is the most simplest I would recommend the usage of Option 6

- As David Fowler (ASP.NET Architect at Microsoft suggested) [prefer `async`/`await` over returning a `Task` directly](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-asyncawait-over-directly-returning-task)
- Even though [Polly `await`s the passed `Func<Task<TResult>>` method](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/AsyncCircuitBreakerEngine.cs#L25), which is passed to the `ExecuteAsync`, it is an implementation detail and you should not rely on this